# Is it possible to impose periodic boundary conditions on Chebyshev differentiation matrix?

Tags: poisson, collocation, chebyshev

This is a repost from another community, it was recommended that I post it here instead.

I have been using the Chebyshev collocation method for solving PDEs. In particular to solve a 3D generalized Poisson's equation. One of the problems I am facing is that one of my dimensions is periodic and would require periodic BCs. I have been following with the Trefethen's book "Spectral Methods in Matlab", but so far do not see anything like that. I am wondering if it's not possible even though we can apply FFTs to these derivative matrices to speed up things.

A little background, I am solving for 3D fluid equations to study ionospheric turbulence, basically I am writing a potential solver to solve for a current closure (charge conservation) and this is my equation:
$$\textbf{a}\nabla_{\perp} \cdot \left(n \nabla_{\perp} \phi \right) + \textbf{b} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left( n \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}\right) = \textbf{S} $$

Originally, I was able to solve this above equation in 2D using spectral methods with Fourier basis function with periodic BCs, but with the addition of the third non-periodic dimension I thought of rewriting everything using Chebyshev. Any suggestions or examples using periodic BCs with chebyshev matrices would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Typically, these types of problems are solved by the Chebyshev-Fourier method: Chebyshev for the non-periodic, and Fourier for the periodic direction. Why do you want to apply the Chebyshev approximation in every direction?

Comment: I wasn't aware I can separate my basis functions based on the direction like that. I guess, I am not quiet sure how the iterative solver would look like with 2D with Fourier and 1D with chebyshev basis.

Comment: What are the non-periodic BC's in the third dimension? Zero Dirichlet?

Comment: I would like to have an option between Neumann and Dirichlet. But, yes for simplicity now it's just zero Dirichlet.

Comment: I think I will create a separate question where I show in details how I construct my solver for x,y using periodic and Fourier basis and how I would add the third dimension to get people's input.